# php mysql login with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, forms

I'm trying to make a form to login users into my webpage using mysql db.

My page `index.php` has a form which posts to `doLogin.php` which checks user/pass from mysql database. Once a user is verified, I would like to show the username in a div to show they have been logged in.

#### index.php

**JQuery**

```
$document.ready(function() {

    $("#login_b").click(function() {
        var action = $("#form1").attr('action');
        var form_data = {
            username: $("#username").val(),
            password: $("#password").val(),
            is_ajax: 1
        };

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
                url: action,
                data: form_data,
                success: function(response)
                {
                    if(response == 'success')
                        alert( username + "Te logeaste correctamente","alert window");
                        document.location.href='index_spa.php';
                        $("#user_data").html( username + " online");
                    if(response == 'empty')
                        alert("No hay datos para validar","alert window");
                        $("#user_data").html("Campos vacios");
                        document.location.href='index_spa.php'
                    if(response == 'incorrect')
                        alert("Error en los datos introducidos","alert window");
                        $("#user_data").html("Datos incorrectos");
                        document.location.href='index_spa.php'
                    if(response == 'inactive')
                        alert("Cuenta no activada","alert window");
                        $("#user_data").html("La cuenta no est&aacute; activada");
                        document.location.href='index_spa.php'
                }
            });
        return false;
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="user_data"></div>
<div id="login_box">
    <form id="form1" action="doLogin.php" method="post">
        <div id="border">
            <table class="table_text" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>Usuario:</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="username" class="input" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Clave:</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="password" name="password" class="input" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="right">
                        <a class="link_login" target="_new" href="register.php">Registrarse</a>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <input id="login_b" type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" class="button" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

#### doLogin.php

```
<?php
//allow sessions to be passed so we can see if the user is logged in
session_start();
ob_start();
//connect to the database so we can check, edit, or insert data to our users table
$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'winterfall', '14789632qwerty') or die(mysql_error());
$db = mysql_select_db('clientes', $con) or die(mysql_error());
//include out functions file giving us access to the protect() function made earlier
include "./functions.php";
//If the user has submitted the form
if($_POST['submit']){
    //protect the posted value then store them to variables
    $username = protect($_POST['username']);
    $password = protect($_POST['password']);
    //Check if the username or password boxes were not filled in
    if(!$username || !$password){
        //if not display an error message
        echo "empty";
    }else{
        //if the were continue checking
        //select all rows from the table where the username matches the one entered by the user
        $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '".$username."'");
        $num = mysql_num_rows($res);
        //check if there was not a match
        if($num == 0){
            //if not display an error message
            echo "empty";
        }else{
            //if there was a match continue checking
            //select all rows where the username and password match the ones submitted by the user
            $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '".$username."' AND `password` = '".$password."'");
            $num = mysql_num_rows($res);
            //check if there was not a match
            if($num == 0){
                //if not display error message
                echo "incorrect";
            }else{
                //if there was continue checking
                //split all fields fom the correct row into an associative array
                $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
                //check to see if the user has not activated their account yet
                if($row['active'] != 1){
                    //if not display error message
                    echo "no active";
                }else{
                    //if they have log them in
                    //set the login session storing there id - we use this to see if they are logged in or not
                    $_SESSION['uid'] = $row['id'];
                    //show message
                    echo "success";
                    //update the online field to 50 seconds into the future
                    $time = date('U')+50;
                    mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `online` = '".$time."' WHERE `id` = '".$_SESSION['uid']."'");
                    //redirect them to the usersonline page
                    //header('Location: usersOnline.php');
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

please help me.

thank you

Comment: -1 "Not showing the contant I want" does not help us understand the problem. What content are you expecting to be shown? What do you see instead?

Comment: what's the matter with you? why that negative point???

Comment: You need to explain what is not working. You cannot say "does not show what I want" as we do not know what you want. I initially asked for you to expand on the problem 2 hours ago and you did not. So after giving you the opportunity to improve your question, which you did not take, I down voted it for being a poorly asked question.

Comment: yes it could be a poorly question. I explain to you: after being reading a lot of tutorials and much code about it i'm at the same point. i mean, php file that read user/pass from form action and read mysql database to check and write username in a div that is empty. that's my only problem. please be patient and not give more negative points 'cause it's hard to collect.

Comment: I can only down vote once - I am afraid it is other people that have down-voted aswell. I will help you improve your question and then I will remove my downvote. I am going to change your question a bit now, if it is wrong when I change it, just let me know and we can change it back and try something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry if this seems like an odd question, but did your form work as you expected with `doLogin.php` before adding the JQuery functionality or is this the first time that you have tried it?

The main problem that I see with your JQuery is that you do not have open and closing brackets within your `if` statements.

So

```
if(response == 'success')
    alert( username + "Te logeaste correctamente","alert window");
    document.location.href='index_spa.php';
    $("#user_data").html( username + " online");
if(response == 'empty')
    alert("No hay datos para validar","alert window");
    $("#user_data").html("Campos vacios");
    document.location.href='index_spa.php'
.....
```

Should be

```
if(response == 'success'){
    alert( username + "Te logeaste correctamente","alert window");
    document.location.href='index_spa.php';
    $("#user_data").html( username + " online");
}
if(response == 'empty'){
    alert("No hay datos para validar","alert window");
    $("#user_data").html("Campos vacios");
    document.location.href='index_spa.php'
}
.....
```

You can also try using `alert( response )` to see what you are getting back from the server.

Comment: having login form inside index.php it is my priority to refresh index.php with validation form. that's reason for using ajax, i haven't used ajax never in my life. But i've found some examples for validating forms. in these examples, there's no brackets. but i think i'll do it in jquery

Comment: @RaphaelD.G Excellent - what was the main problem?